# How do I do this alias in BASH

Tags: bash, alias

At work, in csh, I use this alias in my .alias file:

```
alias n  'nedit \!* &'
```

I can then type --> n file1 file2 ... file, and nedit will start in the background with each of the files in a separate tabbed window, leaving my terminal free for other tasks.

Now, in BASH, I can't do the file insertions without using a function, but then how do I also get the application in the background?

```
function n()
{
   nedit "$@";
}
```

If I add an & between the second quote and the semi-colon, I get a syntax error.

Thanks for the help,
Eric

Comment: You might consider using screen instead of attempting to break things out like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just an ampersand, no semicolon:

```
function n()
{
   nedit "$@" &
}
```